# Fragment aparece tras el AppBarLayout, cuando debería estar debajo

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, material-design

Al comenzar el proyecto, el fragment que contiene una lista de CadrViews aparece escondido tras el AppBarLayout (ver imagen). En vez de estar debajo.

[image: Fragment con CardView inicia detrás del AppBarLayout]

XML Activity:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.reparappbeta.Ejemplo">
  
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

XML Fragment:

```html
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

XML Tab 'Servicios'

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/reciclador"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:background="#E0E0E0"/>

    <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/refresh2"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/accent"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/primary"
        fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/ripple" />
    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Prueba usando el comando:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/id_tabs"
```

en tu fragment principal, le colocas el id, del elemento debajo del cual debería aparecer :D